# GML 3.2 to Turtle RDF

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, gml, turtle-rdf

What would be a valid Turtle RDF representation of the following GML 3.2 description?

```
<gml:Point gml:id="Point.8307">
    <gml:pos srsDimension="3">3512838.613 5516087.399 126.135</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
```

Is there an official GML 3.2 ontology that can be used? 
How would it look like?
This way?:

```
@prefix gml: <http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2#> .

gml:Point 
    gml:id "Point.8307" ;
    gml:pos [
        gml:pos_x 3512838.613 ; 
        gml:pos_y 5516087.399 ;
        gml:pos_z 126.135 
    ]
.
```

Comment: Have a look at [GeoSPARQL](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/geosparql).